# Spring Data JPA - Writing a complex Query Method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using: Spring Data Repository + Hibernate

I have a table: `Post`, with the field: `User userBoard` and `Date dateCreated`

I have a table: `User`, with the field: `List<User> friends`

To the question I have to specify the parameters:

- User *user*
- Date *dateCreated*
- Pageable *page*

I would like to achieve:

Download all posts by *user* + all posts by users on the list of user's friends for *user*, then posts are to have a date earlier than the date *dateCreated* sorting the collected items from the oldest date to all this, of course-pages *page*

I know that I can achieve this without the native query, so please advice on how to go about it. I can write a simple question, but the complex is no longer in the native query.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Consider changing title, since you don't want to create native query anymore. Instead of describing your tables/classes post the source code with your mappings. If you already have native query post it as well.

Comment: What is your current native query ?

Comment: Just to clear, you are using Spring Data JPA ? and you are looking to write a "Query Method" ? Please post your Repository (java class).

Comment: Don't describe uour code. Post it.

Answer (score 6):

The following JPA query will work as required:

```
@Query("SELECT "
    + "  DISTINCT p "
    + "FROM "
    + "  Post p "
    + "INNER JOIN "
    + "  p.user.friends f "
    + "WHERE "
    + "  (p.user = ?1 OR f = ?1) "
    + "AND p.dateCreated < ?2")
Page<Post> findAllByUserOrFriendsAndDateCreated(User user
                                               , Date dateCreated
                                               , Pageable page);
```

Then call this method as:

```
findAllByUserOrFriendsAndDateCreated(user
                                    , date
                                    , new PageRequest(pageNumber
                                                      , pageSize
                                                      , new Sort("dateCreated"));
```

[Sample project](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/41625874) available on Github.

This query cannot be generated out of a method name because it requires one of the clauses to be enclosed in brackets, something not supported by Spring Data yet.